# How to control the connection while uploading to AWS S3?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, backup, aws-directory-service

Is there a way to control the connection while uploading from my servers to the AWS Storage? to be clear, Azcopy is so powerful to upload to AWS, so most of our bandwidth consumed and this is affecting our DataCenter !! So is there a command to let Azcopy limit the connection for every transfer (max 100M speed for every server ), so if I have 3 servers, the consumed bandwidth must be 300M only from the total speed (1000M).

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `azcopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) shows that it can limit its own bandwidth usage:

> **--cap-mbps float** Caps the transfer rate, in megabits per second. Moment-by-moment throughput might vary slightly from the cap. If this option is set to zero, or it is omitted, the throughput isn't capped.

Comment: I had the chance to read this article before and to apply the commands but no way, the bandwidth consumed by as much as 70% by that one single server, and this not acceptable for our Datacenter, also I had the chance to see this article, it is more specific https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip139.html   but no way, can you give me something very specific to apply my scenario for each server in the same time?  Thanks

Comment: Although I did not find the answer in your response and you did not respond to my comment, I did not lose hope and I found my answer in the Spiceworks community, I hope you will have time to explain your answers in the future.